# Parsing a YouTube thumbnail in an iframe with Jsoup

Tags: java, android, iframe, youtube, jsoup

I would like to display the default thumbnail image of this YouTube URL in my Android app:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FXx_gbdIUKg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

This is my method for doing so:

```
  static String parseThumbnail(String youTubeURL){
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.parse(youTubeURL);
        Elements youtubeElements = document.select("FXx_gbdIUKg");
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document iframeDoc =  Jsoup.parse(youtubeElements.get(0).data());
        Elements iframeElements = iframeDoc.select("iframe");
    return iframeElements.attr("http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+youtubeElements+"/default.jpg");
```

the iframe is within the "content:encoded" node, so I'm calling this method here.

```
String itemYouTubeImage = null;

                 if (XML_TAG_CONTENT_ENCODED.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
                        String contentEncoded = tagNode.getTextContent();
                        itemYouTubeImage = parseThumbnail(contentEncoded);
                        itemImageURL = parseImageFromHTML(contentEncoded);
                        itemContentEncodedText = parseTextFromHTML(contentEncoded);
```

How do I properly do this?

One problem I have is that the compiler tells me that the value `parseThumbnail(contentEncoded)` assigned to `itemYouTubeImage` is never used

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the default thumbnail, this is provided in the `<head>` of the youtube HTML document.  It is not encoded.

```
<link itemprop="thumbnailUrl" 
    href="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2qhzsn3pZgk/maxresdefault.jpg">
```

To select on the attribute value and get the absolute URL:

```
    String youtubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wpqE8OSWrU";

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(youtubeUrl).get();

    String thumbnailUrl = doc
            .select("link[itemprop=thumbnailUrl]")
            .first()
            .absUrl("href");

    System.out.println(thumbnailUrl);
```

**Output**

```
    https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9wpqE8OSWrU/maxresdefault.jpg
```

Read more in the [Jsoup cookbook](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls).